# If a UIButton alpha set to 0, no need to removeFromSuperview?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I've just noticed something interesting with my UIButton.

I'm currently fading the button out so that `button.alpha = 0.0;`

Originally I intended to `[button removeFromSuperview]` as well at this point. However, it seems a button with a 0.0 alpha does not execute, which is about the same as it not being there (and for the purpose of my project, just as fine).

Is this an intended consequence of alpha being 0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hidden `UIControl`s do not respond to events, this includes `alpha = 0.0`'ed elements.

However, if you do not remove the `UIButton` from its superview it might not get deallocated until the superview is deallocated since the superview retains it. This likely isn't a problem, especially if you might re-fade in the button. Just make sure your memory management is correct.

For legibility I would also add `button.enabled = NO` even though it's unecessary functionaly.

Answer (score 1):

If your intent is to simply hide the button, but you will need it again later, setting its `alpha` value is the wrong tool for the job. Just hide it instead with the `hidden` property of `UIView`.

If you don't need the button anymore, then `removeFromSuperview`, as you've already stated.

Mucking with the `alpha` gives the impression that there is some complication with blending implicit in the code.

Write your code for readability. Communicate intent as clearly as possible so the person looking at your code later -- who might be you in 3/6/12/24 months time -- understands it as easily as possible.